# Google sheet: Index Match with greater than and equal to criteria

Tags: google-sheets

**Problem**

1. How to find value under index match with 2 dimensions lookup
2. Using index match with greater than and equal to criteria
3. Adding column without changing data range in index match formula

**Existing data**

```
Table 1: 
*numbers under purchasing no. are the purchasing quantity of the item.

| Column A | Column B          | Column C          | Column D          |
| -------- | ----------------  | ----------------  | ----------------  |
| Item     | purchasing no.1   | purchasing no.2   | purchasing no.3   |
| apple    | 2                 | 10                | 2                 |
| banana   | 5                 | 2                 | 7                 |



Table 2
| Column A | Column B | Column C       |
| -------- | -------- | -------------- |
| Item     | order    | purchasing no. |
| apple    | 7        | value needed   |
```

**What I want**

1. After entering "apple" in `'Table 2'!A2` , and "7" in `'Table 2'!B2` , `'Table 2'!C2`  should give me "purchasing no.2" as value I need. Since the 7th apple is bought under purchasing no.2.
2. Even if Column E is added afterwards in Table 1, formula in `'Table 2'!C2`  should stay the same and output the correct purchasing no.

Here is the formula I wrote in `'Table 2'!C2`

```
=index('Table 1'!B1:D1,match(A2,'Table 1'!A2:A,0),match(B2,indirect(concatenate("'Table 1'!B",match(A2,'Table 1'!A:A,0),":","D",match(A2,'Table 1'!A:A,0))),-1))
```

**Problem**

1. If I enter "7" in `'Table 2'!B2` , `'Table 2'!C2`  will give "purchasing no.2", which is correct. However, if I enter "12" in `'Table 2'!C2` , `'Table 2'!C2`  will display #N/A, which should be "purchasing no.2" as well, since 12th apple is bought under purchasing no.2.
2. If I added column E in Table 1, `'Table 2'!C2`  only gives value between `'Table 1'!B1:D1` .

*note: using index & match is not necessary, if there's other formula can avoid the encountered problems

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
=xlookup(AB9,SCAN(,FILTER(B:Z,A:A=AA9),LAMBDA(ac,cv,ac+cv)),B1:Z1,,1)
```

- 

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Your formula works perfectly fine. Just a tiny problem, according to your formula, if I add a column after Z, nothing will come out since the setting range of formula is Table 1 B2:Z. Is there any way that I can add as many columns as I want but without adjusting the range in formula?

Comment: Try (https://i.imgur.com/IhspBQu.png) `=xlookup(B2,SCAN(,FILTER(INDIRECT("Sheet!B$1:"&MAX(ROWS(Sheet!A:A))),Sheet!A:A=A2),LAMBDA(ac,cv,ac+cv)),Sheet!B$1:$1,,1)` PS: `Sheet` is the taken Tab name here

Answer (score 0):

You need cummulative sums to find the place of that last "apple". You can set it by inserting SCAN in your formula:

```
SCAN(0,INDEX('Table 1'!B2:Z,match(A2,'Table 1'!A2:A,0)),LAMBDA(a,v,a+v))
```

And for finding that higher value you can benefit from XLOOKUP that will return the header corresponding to that match:

```
=IFNA(XLOOKUP(B2, SCAN(0,INDEX('Table 1'!B2:Z,match(A2,'Table 1'!A2:A,0)),LAMBDA(a,v,a+v)), 'Table 1'!B1:Z1,,1))
```

And finally if you want it to work for the whole column just by inserting one only formula in C2 you can use MAP:

```
=MAP(A2:A,B2:B,LAMBDA(av,bv,
IFNA(XLOOKUP(bv,
  SCAN(0,INDEX('Table 1'!B2:Z,match(av,'Table 1'!A2:A,0)),LAMBDA(a,v,a+v)),
  'Table 1'!B1:Z1,,1))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Your formula works perfectly fine. 
Just a tiny problem, according to your formula, if I add a column after Z, nothing will come out since the setting range of formula is Table 1 B2:Z. Is there any way that I can add as many columns as I want but without adjusting the range in formula?

Comment: You can always extend your formula to a full column or a full row, but to do both is not so automate. Not impossible, but it will not help. What I suggest you is to always keep the last column of your formula empty and insert new columns to the left of it; that way they'll always be included automatically!